# Catch statements are not executed when TestNG listeners are on

Tags: java, testng

I have a ITestListener to note test results. 
 In my locator class if I try to handle something in catch statement, none of the code inside the catch is executed. 
For ex : I am trying to handle a WebElement that may or may not throw exception. When it throws exceptions, I should handle in the catch statement and locate different element. Since catch statement is not being executed and when the exception occurs, the applications just halts. 
Is there a way I could run the catch statement even when onTestFailure method is ON from TestNG ? 
Please suggest a solution.

```
//Test Script 
public boolean loginVerification(String username, String password) {

        try {

            utilities.click(helloSignInLink, "elementToBeClickable");
            reportLog("debug","info","Clicked on SignIn link");

            utilities.sendText(loginID, username);
            reportLog("debug","info","Username entered");

            utilities.sendText(passwordID, password);
            reportLog("debug","info","Password entered");

            utilities.click(submit, "elementToBeClickable");
            reportLog("debug","info","Clicked on submit button");

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            isTrue = driver.getTitle().contains("Vectors");

        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            reportLog("debug","info","Unable to login with username : "+username+" , error message : "+e);
            isTrue = false;
        }

        return isTrue;

    }
```

Comment: Add the code please.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Hey, Alex. Just modified the post with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to catch `Throwable` - not just an `Exception`. Another thing is that when you catch something the excepttion does not really go up the stack so TestNG would never know if anything went wrong in your test and test listener would not detect failure. There is the way to push the exception further on after you have cought it. Like:

```
    catch(Throwable e) {
        reportLog("debug","info","Unable to login with username : "+username+" , error message : "+e);
        isTrue = false;
        throw e;
    }
```

Can you correct your approach and let us know if the issue still exists?

**P.S.** - I also cannot see any assertions in your code. Assert results or Exception define the test result.

Comment: You are awesome, this actually worked. Oh btw the code you see above is in my locator class and not a test class. I have assertions added in my Test class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means you are not catching the same error catch block.

Either use the same exception like `TimeoutException` so this block will only if `TimeoutException` occur. If you not sure about the error use generic exception block like  `Exception` it will for sure going to execute if any error occur. In this case `Exception` will not execute for `TimeoutException` only because you have already specify same

```
    try {
        System.out.println("Your code");
    }catch(TimeoutException t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am using a generic exception.